# upload php directory

Tags: php, apache

у меня в `phpinfo()` написано, что, если делаем загрузку файла, то должно сохранть в директорию

```
upload_tmp_dir  d:/wamp/tmp d:/wamp/tmp
```

проверяю на коде из одного урока:

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
// In an application, this could be moved to a config file
$upload_errors = array(
    // http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
    UPLOAD_ERR_OK               => "No errors.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE     => "Larger than upload_max_filesize.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE  => "Larger than form MAX_FILE_SIZE.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL        => "Partial upload.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE        => "No file.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR => "No temporary directory.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE => "Can't write to disk.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION  => "File upload stopped by extension."
);
$error = $_FILES['file_upload']['error'];
$message = $upload_errors[$error];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_FILES['file_upload']);
echo "</pre>";
echo "<hr />";

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<?php
// The maximum file size (in bytes) must be declared before the file input field
// and can't be larger than the setting for upload_max_filesize in php.ini.
//
// This form value can be manipulated. You should still use it, but you rely
// on upload_max_filesize as the absolute limit.
//
// Think of it as a polite declaration: "Hey PHP, here comes a file less than X..."
// PHP will stop and complain once X is exceeded.
//
// 1 megabyte is actually 1,048,576 bytes.
// You can round it unless the precision matters.
?>

        <?php if(!empty($message)) { echo "<p>{$message}</p>"; } ?>
        <form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

          <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
          <input type="file" name="file_upload" />

          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

оно как бы сохраняет, но файла в указаной выше директории нет.

Как можно узнать, где искать загруженный файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

обычно после загрузки принято вызывать функцию [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php) для перемещения загруженного файла в **требуемое** место.

если всё настроено верно, она обращается именно к тому каталогу, куда *http*-сервер временно и сохранил файл.

неплохой пример загрузки файлов приведён, например, [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

---

по поводу «отсутствия» загруженного файла:

насколько я понимаю, раз в обработчике загрузки вы **ничего** не сделали с временно сохранённым файлом, то он для вас просто «потерян», так как временные файлы на то и временные, что **удаляются** после использования.